# What is an asymptote?

Tags: geometry, biology

I'm a student of Zoology having class XII Maths background.

I stumbled upon asymptote while studying [S-shaped growth form](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=HttcVh_XbWgC&pg=PT60&dq=s-shaped%20growth%20form&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU7NWY0LzRAhWBpI8KHf2EBekQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=s-shaped%20growth%20form&f=false) in ecology. I tried to google it up and found wikipedia define it in the following way:

> In analytic geometry, an asymptote  of a curve is a line such that the distance between the curve and the line **approaches zero as they tend to infinity**.

I don't get the last part. What does it mean?

**NOTE:** K (carrying capacity) is the asymptote in the diagram.

Comment: Without going into the details it means that your curve will approach the line $y=K$ when $x$ gets very large.

Comment: If you write that as answer I can mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going into the details it means that your curve will approach the line $y=K$ when $x$ gets very large.

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively, in your example in the diagram, it means that the number of individuals will approach $K$ as time increases (becomes very large).